# Unexpected errors I do not know how to solve

Tags: c, unix, error-handling, sh, dynamic-memory-allocation

After some troubleshooting I am still getting some errors on this code that I do not know how to solve... this code basically divides an image in slices and uses convolution to blur the pixels. Yet I do not know how to eliminate the errors I get and also convolve the image using the function  "multiconvolve_2".

(I have attached the code and the console error message, any help and explannation is well appreciated).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>    // Unix-like system calls read and write
#include <fcntl.h>     // Unix-like system calls to open and close
#include<pthread.h>
#include "myutils.h"
//gcc convolution.c myutils.c -o conv -lpthread
#define WIDTH  1024
#define HEIGHT 1024
#define KLEN      7    // works with 3 or 7
#define KSIZE    49    // KLEN * KLEN

#define MAX(a, b) (a < b ? b : a)
#define MIN(a, b) (a < b ? a : b)

unsigned char* pixels; // a pointer to the original image (needs malloc)
unsigned char* target; // a pointer to the target of convolution (needs malloc)

typedef struct kernel_struct {
  int values[KSIZE];
  int sum;
} kernel_type;

kernel_type filter; // the 3x3 kernel used to convolve the image

static unsigned char tga[18];

// read a 1024x1024 image
void read_tga(char* fname) {
  int fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY);
  read(fd, tga, 18);
  read(fd, pixels, WIDTH * HEIGHT);
  close(fd);
}

// write a 1024x1024 image
void write_tga(char* fname, unsigned char *image) {
  int fd = open(fname, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644);
  write(fd, tga, sizeof(tga));
  printf("Created file %s: Writing pixel size %d bytes\n", fname, WIDTH * HEIGHT);
  write(fd, image, WIDTH * HEIGHT);
  close(fd);
}

// create a random filter
void random_filter() {
  filter.sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < KSIZE; i++) {
    filter.values[i] = rand() % 10;
    filter.sum += filter.values[i];
  }
}

void gaussian_3x3() {
  int values[] = { 1, 2, 1,
                   2, 4, 2,
                   1, 2, 1 };

  memcpy(filter.values, values, KSIZE * sizeof(int));

  filter.sum = 16;
}

void gaussian_7x7() {
  int values[] = { 0,  0,  1,   2,  1,  0, 0,
                   0,  3, 13,  22, 13,  3, 0,
                   1, 13, 59,  97, 59, 13, 1,
                   2, 22, 97, 159, 97, 22, 2,
                   1, 13, 59,  97, 59, 13, 1,
                   0,  3, 13,  22, 13,  3, 0,
                   0,  0,  1,   2,  1,  0, 0 };

  memcpy(filter.values, values, KSIZE * sizeof(int));

  filter.sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < KSIZE; i++)
    filter.sum += filter.values[i];
}

// create a Gaussian filter
void gaussian_filter() {
  if (KSIZE == 9) gaussian_3x3();
  else if (KSIZE == 49) gaussian_7x7();
}

// create a horizonal filter
void horizontal_filter() {
  for (int i = 0; i < KSIZE; i++) {
    int row = i / KLEN;
    if (3 * row < KLEN)
      filter.values[i] = -1;
    else if (KLEN < 2 * row)
      filter.values[i] = 1;
    else
      filter.values[i] = 0;
  }

  filter.sum = 0;
}

// create a vertical filter
void vertical_filter() {
  for (int i = 0; i < KSIZE; i++) {
    int col = i % KLEN;
    if (3 * col < KLEN)
      filter.values[i] = -1;
    else if (KLEN < 2 * col)
      filter.values[i] = 1;
    else
      filter.values[i] = 0;
  }

  filter.sum = 0;
}

void interchange() {
  unsigned char* aux = pixels;
  pixels = target;
  target = aux;
}

// compute the target pixel at (x,y)
void compute_target_pixel(int x, int y) {
  int i, j, sum = 0;
  int delta = (KLEN - 1) / 2;
  for (i = -delta; i <= delta; ++i)
    for (j = -delta; j <= delta; ++j)
      if (0 <= x + i && x + i < WIDTH && 0 <= y + j && y + j < HEIGHT)
        sum += filter.values[(i + delta) * KLEN + (j + delta)] * pixels[(x + i) * HEIGHT + (y + j)];

  if(filter.sum > 0) target[x * HEIGHT + y] = sum / filter.sum;
  else target[x * HEIGHT + y] = sum;
}

void convolve() {
  int x, y;
  for (x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
    for (y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
      compute_target_pixel(x, y);
}

void multi_convolve_1(int iter) {
  // Add Code here
  int i;
  for (i=1;i<iter;i++){
    convolve();
    interchange();
      
  }
}

void* convolveThread(void* idx){
  int* params=idx;
  int threadid=params[0];
  int totalthreads=params[1];
  int x,y;
  int numberows= WIDTH/totalthreads;
  for(x=numberows*threadid;x <numberows*(threadid+1); ++x){
    for(y=0;y < HEIGHT; ++y){
      compute_target_pixel(x,y);
    }
  }

  return NULL;
}

 void convolve_threaded(int numerodethreads){
   
   pthread_t thread[numerodethreads];
   int* params = malloc(2*sizeof(int));


   int i;
   
   params[1]=numerodethreads;
   for(i=0;i<numerodethreads;i++){
      params[0]=i;
      pthread_create( &thread[i],NULL, convolveThread, params);


   }
   for(i=0;i<numerodethreads;i++){
      pthread_join(thread,NULL);
      free(params);
   }
 }

multiconvolve_2(int iter, int nthreads){
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<iter;i++){
    convolve_threaded(nthreads);
    interchange();
  }
}


void load_image() {
  read_tga("test.tga");  // read the image
  memcpy(target, pixels, WIDTH*HEIGHT);
}

int main(void) {
  // Allocate images
  pixels = malloc(WIDTH * HEIGHT);
  target = malloc(WIDTH * HEIGHT);

  load_image();

  // create a filter
  gaussian_filter();
  //vertical_filter();
  //horizontal_filter();

  load_image();
  multiconvolve_2(8,8);

  //gcc convolution.c myutils.c -pthread -o conv
  //./conv
  
  // write the convolved image
  write_tga("output.tga", target);

  free(pixels);
  free(target);
  return 0;
}
```

After creating the executable "conv" I get this errors:

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Don't know if it's the problem... but `params` is allocated once (for `2` ints -- should it be `numerodethreads` ints??) and freed `numerodethreads` times (twice??) inside a loop. The rule is: one malloc ==> one free; I don't think your case is worthy of an exception.

Comment: What does this have to do with the `sh` tag?

Answer (score 1):

In this for loop

```
for(i=0;i<numerodethreads;i++){
   pthread_join(thread,NULL);
   free(params);
}
```

there is called `free( params )` that tries to free the same allocated dynamically memory in this declaration

```
int* params = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
```

`numerodethreads` times.

Also it seems you mean

```
pthread_join(thread[i],NULL);
```

instead of

```
pthread_join(thread,NULL);
```